# Which of the two elastic search find query is more efficient?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to elastic search and learning its dsl. I've written two queries that fetch the same result set.

**Query 1**

```
{ "query": {
      "bool": {
        "filter": {
          "bool": {
          "must": [
              {
                  "match": {
                      "vin": "okhifeb"
                  }
              },
              {
                  "match": {
                      "reportType": "OVERSPEEDING"
                  }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                    "startTime": {
                    "gte": "2023-07-01T00:00:00"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "range": {
                    "endTime": {
                    "lte": "2023-07-18T00:00:00"
                    }
                }
            }
          ]
        }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

**Query 2**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "vin.keyword": ["okhifeb"]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "reportType": "OVERSPEEDING"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "startTime": {
                        "gte": "2023-07-01T00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "endTime": {
                        "lte": "2023-07-18T00:00:00"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Which query will be more efficient? Both queries have similar **took** values. Which is more efficient in general - terms or match? How efficient does **filter** make the query and when is it useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one, since your constraints are about exact matches and you don't need scoring, `bool/must` necessarily implies scoring.

Rewritten optimal query but without the unnecessary nested `bool/must`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "vin": "okhifeb"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "reportType": "OVERSPEEDING"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "startTime": {
              "gte": "2023-07-01T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "endTime": {
              "lte": "2023-07-18T00:00:00"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```